# Как реализовать печать класса List С++

Tags: c++, классы, list, шаблоны-с++, список

Хочу реализовать печать всего класса List по порядку. List реализую на шаблонах, а в них я не очень силен. К примеру list от int и прочие встроенные типы выводит без проблем, а вот пользовательские типы не могу понять как выводить.

К примеру код метода печати:

```
template <typename T>
void List <T>::PrintFromHead()
{
cout << "Come the method PrintFromHead:" << endl;
Node <T> *print = head;
while (print)
{
    cout << print->data << endl;
    print = print->pNext;
}
cout << endl;
}
```

Класс который хочу вывести

```
class Person {
 public:
char name[len];
char sec_name[len];
char birthday[len];
char ph_num[len];

void Enter_Data() {
    cout << "Enter name" << endl;
    cin >> name;
}
};
```

Решил проблему следующим образом

```
class Person {

private:
char name[len];
char sec_name[len];
char birthday[len];
char ph_num[len];

public:
//Ввод данных о человеке
void Enter_Data() {
    cout << "Введите имя: ";
    cin >> name;

    cout << "Введите фамилию: ";
    cin >> sec_name;

    cout << "Введите номер телефона: ";
    cin >> ph_num;
}

friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Person &cur);
};

//Вывод данных объекта
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Person &cur)
{
out << cur.name << " " << cur.sec_name << " "
    << " " << cur.ph_num << " " << endl;
return out;
}

template <typename T>
class List {

private:
template <typename T>
class Node {
public:
    T data;
    Node* p_next;

    Node() {
        data = T();
        p_next = nullptr;
    }
};

int size_l;
Node<T>* head;
Node<T>* last;

public:
List();

void Add(T data);

void print() {
    cout << "Come the method PrintFromHead:" << endl;
    Node <T> *print = head;
    while (print)
    {
        cout << print->data << endl;
        print = print->p_next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
};
```

Comment: Для класса Person Вам нужно переопределить вывод в поток "<<", по моему так, давно не писал на с++.

Comment: Я это понимаю, но долблюсь и не могу понять, как сам метод должен выглядеть и какие параметры принимать. Ох эти шаблоны...

Comment: По моему это то, что Вам нужно https://ravesli.com/urok-133-peregruzka-operatorov-vvoda-i-vyvoda/ .

Comment: Почитав и посмотрев все более внимательно и потратив 2 часа, все заработало!

Comment: Приятно иметь дело с человеком, который учиться и думает сам. Посмотрите, возможно, что Ваше самостоятельное решение есть смысл добавить сюда в качестве ответа. Я думаю, что это принесет Вам балы в репутацию.

Comment: @Mii ответ на вопрос добавляйте в ответы с помощью кнопки "ответить на собственный вопрос", а не путём редактирования вопроса